# Adding value in register to memory operand produces 'error operation size not specified'

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
section .data 

var dd 10

section .text 

add [var] , eax
```

for above code nasm gives error operation size not specified,

but if we reverse it `add eax, [var]` it doesn't  gives error.
   why error for only first and not for second type ?

Comment: Both versions compile fine with my NASM 2.11.06, what version do you have? You can check it with `nasm -v`

Comment: @MargaretBloom 2.12.11  compiling using command `nasm filename.asm -f elf32  -g`

Comment: WAG: Try `add dword [var], eax`. Rationale: The assembler needs to disambiguate.

Comment: @FrankC. NASM  should be able to disambiguate by seeing that the source is a 32-bit register (EAX) and be able to move it to the destination as 32-bits. If it were moving an immediate value to a memory address then I can see the necessity to disambiguate. I've been using NASM for well over a decade and I do not recall a time where this wouldn't assemble.

Comment: @ryan, are you absolutely sure you got an error with `add [var] , eax` . I am wondering if you tried to do something like `add [var] , 1` (adding an immediate value to the value at a memory location). That should give you the error `operation size not specified`. If moving an immediate value to memory you need to specify the size with something like `add [var] , dword 1` . This says that the value 1 should be treated/encoded as a 32-bit _DWORD_ and stored in the destination memory address as a 32-bit value.

Comment: In my comment to Frank I meant to say _If it were ADDING an immediate value to a memory address_

Comment: Downvoted for invalid premise, since it's attracted two bogus answers already.  If you were really using `add [var] , 1`, then edit the question to that.

Comment: Closing as a duplicate of a question with a proper explanation, even though in this current stat it's not really a dup.

Answer (score -2):

You need specify size like this:

```
add dword [var],eax
```

Comment: No you don't.  In NASM, the register operand implies the operand size.  Comments on the question point out that other people can assemble both ways just fine with NASM.

Answer (score -4):

Because the first operand is the destination operand and needs to be a register so instead just move it back :

```
add eax, [var]
mov [var], eax
```

Comment: The [_ADD_](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ADD.html) instruction supports the destination being a memory address and the source being a register. In this case  `add [var], eax` should add the value of _EAX_ to the data at the address associated with the label `var`. From the x86 instruction set `ADD r/m32, r32 - Add r32 to r/m32.`