# Why operand must have size in one line but not the other in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, emu8086

Looking at the picture, on line 34 I had to write the `word ptr` for this to work, while on line 44 I didn't.
Why is that? [image]

Can't the compiler know that 0020h is a word just like 0FF20h is a word?
Adding 0 to 0020h making it 00020h or anything like that doesn't work either.

I am using MASM on 80x86. emu8086, also tried on dosbox v0.74

Comment: `0020H` could also be just a byte but `0FF20H` doesn't fit in a single byte I guess.  Not sure though, just a hunch.

Comment: Note that you had to write `0FF20H` with a leading zero too so if the assembler really relied on the length of the literal, it could have thought that was a dword ...  similarly for `0FFH`. It would be a dangerous game. Note sensible assemblers don't even allow your second form without explicit size. That's just a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: yes it is possible to write an assembler that the number of digits in the number indicates the size 0000h 16 bits and 00h 8 bits.  But that is generally not how they work.  Your confusing is valid, the tool should really force it all the time for consistency, but clearly doesnt...I assume it doesnt throw an error if you add the WORD PTR to line 44?

Comment: You should use the `word ptr` also on line 44, to show your intent to update 16 bits of memory. The fact that it does compile as expected by accident is irrelevant, especially in something as fragile as assembly you should be rather completely explicit and accurate, for the purpose of review and debugging (for example when you ask something on SO, and post your source, you can bet majority of readers will be unable to tell what is the "default" behaviour of your assembler, so being explicit in every ambiguous case helps a lot with reviews).

Comment: And BTW, I think either Peter Cordes or Michael Petch told me their personal preference of using the size specifier on the memory destination side (in NASM you can write also `mov [si], word 0x20` - but I don't use it), and the reasoning was very solid, by stating `mov word ptr [si],20h` you are saying that you want to modify 16 bits of memory, but you don't mind encoding of constant as 8 bit, if such opcode (`mov word ptr [r],sign-extended-imm8`) does exist, so you give the assembler more accurate information what your really want, and leave him relaxed constraints on constant optimization.

Comment: @Ped7g: Yes, that's my reasoning for putting the size override on the memory operand.  (But note that `mov` doesn't have encodings with narrow immediates, except for `mov r64, sign_extended_imm32`.  ALU instructions like `add word [mem], imm8` exist, though.  It would be a nice code-size saving for x86-64 to use one of the opcode bytes it freed up, like SALC or `POP ES`, as the opcode for a `mov r/m64/32/16, sign-extended-imm8`, giving you `mov eax,1` in 3 bytes.  And the very common `mov qword [mem], 0` in 4 bytes + extra for the addressing mode.  Saving 3 bytes vs. imm32 for memory dst.)

Comment: @user7387595: Are you sure you tried it with emu8086?  Last I heard, its crappy assembler would accept ambiguous instructions like that and picks a default operand size (but I forget which size is the default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is because your assembler strangely and dangerously accepts `0FF20h` as implying `word` operand-size.  But even for your assembler, **leading zeros don't imply operand-size**, just the actual value; presumably it checks the position of the most significant bit.

This is not the case for a well-designed and consistent assembler syntax like NASM: If I try to assemble this in 16-bit mode with `nasm -fbin foo.asm`

```
mov [es: si], 2
mov [es: si], 0ff20H
```

I get these errors:

```
foo.asm:1: error: operation size not specified
foo.asm:2: error: operation size not specified
```

Only a register can imply an operand-size for the whole instruction, not the width of a constant.  (`mov [si], ax` is not ambiguous: there is no form of `mov` where the destination has a different width than the source, and `ax` is definitely `word` sized.)

Same applies for GAS (the GNU assembler), in both AT&T and Intel syntax modes.  (Its Intel-syntax mode is very similar to MASM.)

There's no `mov r/m16, sign_extended_imm8` encoding, but there is for `add` and most ALU operations, so there's no reason for an assembler to assume that `xyz [mem], 0` means byte operand size.  More likely the programmer forgot to specify, so it treats it as an error instead of silently accepting something ambiguous.

`mov word [mem], 0` is a totally normal way to zero a word in memory.

---

Besides all that, **x86 supports 32-bit operand size in 16-bit code, using a `66h` operand-size prefix**.  This is independent from the address-size.

`mov dword ptr es:[si], 0FF20h` is also encodeable, and completely ambiguous with `mov word ptr es:[si], 0FF20h` if you leave out the `size ptr` specifier.

As Jester commented, if leading zeros counted as part of the width of the constant, `0FF20h` could easily be taken as implying `dword`.

> Note that you had to write `0FF20H` with a leading zero too so if the assembler really relied on the length of the literal, it could have thought that was a dword ... similarly for `0FFH`. It would be a dangerous game. Note sensible assemblers don't even allow your second form without explicit size. **That's just a bug waiting to happen**.

(Sensible assemblers include NASM and GAS, like I showed above).

If I were you, I'd be unhappy that my assembler accepted `mov es:[si], 0FF20h` without complaint.  I thought emu8086 was even worse than MASM, and usually accepted stuff like `mov [si], 2` with some default operand size instead of warning even then.

I'm not a big fan of how MASM magically infers operand-size from `symbol db 1, 2, 3` either, but that's not ambiguous, it just means you have to look at how a symbol was declared to know what operand-size it will imply.

Comment: Also related: [Why do we need to disambiguate when adding an immediate value to a value at a memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47445362)