# x86, What function does the size-specifier have here?

Tags: assembly, x86, size, nasm

p.s. the `x86` assembly reprex below assembled/inspected using `NASM 2.15.05 + x86_64 Linux + GDB`

```
section .data
        Snippet db "KANG"
section .text
        global _start
_start:
        nop
; =============================================
        mov ebx,Snippet    ; at 0x804a000
        add <byte|word|dword> [ebx],32
; =============================================
        nop
```

`"KANG"` pointed to by `Snippet` is in memory from `0x804a000` to `0x804a003`:

```
(gdb) print (char) *0x804a000
$1 = 75 'K'
(gdb) print (char) *0x804a001
$2 = 65 'A'
(gdb) print (char) *0x804a002
$3 = 78 'N'
(gdb) print (char) *0x804a003
$4 = 71 'G'
(gdb)
```

Decoding ASCII, I am assuming `KANG` is bit pattern `01001011 01000001 01001110 01000111` in memory from `0x804a000` to `0x804a003`

When I leave out the size-specifier in the `ADD` instruction NASM doesn't assemble as expected:

> ss.asm:9: error: operation size not specified

The `add <specifier> [ebx],32` instruction is supposed to convert the data at `[ebx]` from uppercase to lowercase.

My confusion stems from the observation that irrespective of the size specifier used in the instruction, the result is *always*:

```
(gdb) print (char) *0x804a000
$1 = 107 'k'
(gdb) print (char) *0x804a001
$2 = 65 'A'
(gdb) print (char) *0x804a002
$3 = 78 'N'
(gdb) print (char) *0x804a003
$4 = 71 'G'
(gdb)
```

Considering the `BYTE` tells NASM that we're only writing a single byte to the memory address in EBX. Whereas the `WORD` and `DWORD` specifiers tells that we're writing a word and a double word, respectively.

While I was expecting `byte` to generate the above result. I was expecting the following operations (and results) for the other two size specifiers:

- `WORD`: I was expecting the `WORD` specifier to manipulate 16 side by side bits (the 'K' and 'A' characters) starting at 0x804a000 with the operation `0100101101000001B + 0000000000100000B == 0100101101100001B` resulting in `"KaNG"`
- `DWORD`: similarly I was expecting the `DWORD` specifier to manipulate 32 side by side bits (the 'K','A','N', and 'G' characters) starting at 0x804a000 with the operation `01001011010000010100111001000111B + 00000000000000000000000000100000B == 01001011010000010100111001100111B` resulting in `"KANg"`

Where is my understanding of the operation going wrong?

Comment: That's because the upper 3 bytes of 32 are zero, and adding zero has no effect (if you don't have a carry from the low byte).

Comment: Interestingly, there's an *exact* duplicate of this, using the same `add byte [ebx], 32` vs. `add dword [ebx], 32` example in a case that doesn't carry-out. 
 [Why do we need to disambiguate when adding an immediate value to a value at a memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47445362)  I guess it's from a book or tutorial?

Comment: While the question is answering something similar, it is not answering my question. I have made my question more specific.

Comment: Oh, I see you also have an endianness confusion.  `00000000000000000000000000100000B` is non-zero only in the lowest-address (first in printing order) byte of `dword [ebx]` because x86 is little-endian.  If you want to modify the last byte, you want `add dword [ebx], 32 << 24` or `add byte [ebx+3], 32`

Comment: BTW, you can use AND to unconditionally upcase, or XOR to flip case,  like `and dword [ebx], ~0x20202020` to clear the lower-case bit in all 4 characters.